# Cartesian coordinates conventions

Tags: math-history, coordinate-systems

Is there any historical account of how did the Cartesian coordinate system get its current conventions of orientation and representation? Are there any mathematical reasons for these conventions?

Comment: What conventions are you talking about, specifically? The concept was introduced by Rene Descartes.

Comment: In part I think OP is asking in part why the positive $y$-direction is anticlockwise from the positive $x$-direction, rather than clockwise.

Comment: The right angles, the left-to-right increase of the numbers, the orientation of the three axes against its mirrored one. These sort of stuff. How did these evolve? Is it purely conventional, or hide mathematics?

Comment: For example, early Cartesian systems allowed for oblique axes. Why did this convention is now suspended?

Comment: Travis got it right, although it is not the only convention. I understand that most of them are a history of agreements, for which I ask how to look as well. But if there were also mathematical reasons to these agreements? That is more interesting.

Comment: You should add the tag (math-history) in order to reach the right people.